Cancellation of the Deutschlandticket
Actually, I do not well understand some formulations of sellers of the Deutschlandticket.
Therefore my confusion.
If I buy the Deutschlandticket end of June for the month of July, and I only want to use it in the month of July, can I cancel it until the 10th of July, so that it will be no longer valid (above all no longer liable to pay) in August and  the following months ?
Or as some formulations of sellers seem to suggest, for using the Deutschlandticket in a particular month only, in this case July, I have to buy it beginning of June for the month of July, and for getting it ineffective at the end of July, I have to cancel it until the 10th of June ?

I booked directly with bahn.de: if you cancel the ticket on the 9th is still good for the rest of the month. In one case, I bought a ticket on the 5th and cancelled it the next day since I only needed it for the rest of that month

It's not unlikely that the onerous cancellation terms come directly from Deutsche Bahn itself.  This is akin to the way they do their one-year BahnCard 25 and BahnCard 50: You actually have to cancel six weeks before the expiration date, or they sign you up for another year, and send you to collections if you object.  It's a common thing in Germany, unfortunately.

Btw., sometimes you can buy the Deutschlandticket for part of the month - see https://www.merkur.de/reise/guenstig-preis-anteilig-kalendermonat-nahverkehr-deutschlandticket-bahn-zwei-euro-zr-92330425.html (try deepl.com for translations). Usually you have to stay for another month, then.

@user24582 HVV Switch app allows such purchases. You should only do so if you want it for over a month or if you're getting it before the 10th of month though, else you'll pay for another month. You can buy ahead of time (before 10th of the month you're going to need the dticket on) with a start date, say, last 2 weeks of the month and cancel before the 10th too, then you should only pay for 2 weeks.

The Deutschlandticket was never intended for short term visitors, but for pendlers from home to work and back instead of using an automobile. Thus the conditions were designed for long term  commitments. This is, after all, a ticket that is subsidised with €3 billion Euros for each of the years 2023 and 2024.

Hopefully no one, in their right mind, believes that €49 covers the cost of what this tickets costs in reality. Therefore for those, for which the ticket was intended for, it is not complicated at all. It is a simple monthly payment which is common place in Germany for using public transportation regularly each month.

Seemingly to make everything as complicated as possible and the Deutschland-Ticket unattractive, many vendors have strange and incomprehensible terms and conditions for the sale, one common oddity being that you have to cancel your subscription by the 10th of the calendar month the ticket is valid. If you buy a ticket for July, the subscription must be cancelled by the 10th of July, for the subscription not to be automatically extended for August as well. That is not necessarily a problem if you are able to plan a bit in advance, but makes it impossible to buy a ticket only for the rest of July, if you on the 11th of July or later decides that you could need the Deutschland-Ticket for the rest of the month. If you buy a ticket for the rest of the month on the 11th of July, you are already too late to cancel the subscription and must also pay for August anyway, even if you don't need the ticket.
The easiest way to solve this problem is simply to buy the Deutschland-Ticket from a vendor, which does not have the requirement that you have to cancel by the 10th. There are at least a few vendors with much simpler subscription conditions, I am not sure if I should point you directly to any of them, but mo.pla is often recommended. They allow you to cancel the subscription up until the second last day of the month (for July, that would be 30th of July) and have no further restrictions, which often make it difficult for tourists and visitors to Germany to buy and manage their tickets. Some other vendors even require that you have a German bank account to pay for the subscription. Note, that I am not affiliated with mo.pla and have never used their services.

You can link websites if you mention that you aren't affiliated and it doesn't look like spam. Your answer looks helpfull and is not selling it as spam.

Is there an official list of all vendors?

@GiacomoCatenazzi I don't think so. All public transport operators are allowed to sell the Deutschland-Ticket and I believe most of them do. I would guess that there are somewhere in the ballpark of 100 vendors, all with different conditions for their subscriptions.

Ok, but the seller of your link is not a public transport operator, right? Now I'm confused. But ok, I was thinking a much shorter list.

@GiacomoCatenazzi mo.pla is selling tickets on behalf of Vetter Verkehrsbetriebe: https://www.mein-bus.net/

@Tor-EinarJarnbjo Oh, the whole clause relates only the the word "restrictions".  I read it as relating to "[they] have no further restrictions", which confused me.  I understand what you mean now.
